# Keeping unique rows of a cell in Matlab without considering order

Tags: matlab, unique

I have a `mx4` cell `A` in Matlab.

`A{j,1}` is a `2x2` matrix for each j=1,...,m.

`A{j,2}` is a `2x2` matrix for each j=1,...,m.

`A{j,3}` is a `2x2` matrix for each j=1,...,m.

`A{j,4}` is a `1x2` matrix for each j=1,...,m.

E.g. when `m=4`

```
A{1,1}=[0 -1; 1 1]
A{1,2}=[1 0; 2 1]
A{1,3}=[2 0; 3 1]
A{1,4}=[3 0]

A{2,1}=[0 5; 1 1]
A{2,2}=[1 0; 2 1]
A{2,3}=[2 4; 3 1]
A{2,4}=[1 0]

A{3,1}=[2 0; 3 1]
A{3,2}=[1 0; 2 1]
A{3,3}=[0 -1; 1 1]
A{3,4}=[3 0]

A{4,1}=[3 1; 2 0]
A{4,2}=[2 1; 1 0]
A{4,3}=[0 -1; 1 1]
A{4,4}=[3 0]
```

I want an algorithm keeping the unique sequences `A{j,1} A{j,2} A{j,3} A{j,4}`

(1) **without making distinction
between sequences that have the same 4 components but in a different order**

(2) **making distinction between sequences that have the same 4 components up to a reordering of the row vectors within each component**

For example, with regard to the cell `A` above, the algorithm should keep

```
A{1,1}=[0 -1; 1 1]
A{1,2}=[1 0; 2 1]
A{1,3}=[2 0; 3 1]
A{1,4}=[3 0]

A{2,1}=[0 5; 1 1]
A{2,2}=[1 0; 2 1]
A{2,3}=[2 4; 3 1]
A{2,4}=[1 0]

A{4,1}=[3 1; 2 0]
A{4,2}=[2 1; 1 0]
A{4,3}=[0 -1; 1 1]
A{4,4}=[3 0]
```

Comment: so only A{j,1} A{j,2} A{j,3} can be interchanged and A{j,4} only has to be checked against A{~=j,4}. is performance important?

Comment: No, timing is not important. I have to do it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
solutionvector=true(size(A(:,1))); %assue all a different

[~,b,c]=unique(cell2mat(A(:,4)),'rows');%find which {j,4} are the same

for i=1:max(c) %go throuth each unique A{j,4}
    if sum(c==i)>1 %if there is more than one entry
       for j=1:sum(c==i)-1 %for the amount of equal entries minus the last
           entries=find(c==i); %get the indicies of the following entries
            for k=j+1:sum(c==i) %compare the following entries with j
                if( any(arrayfun(@(x) isequal(A(entries(j),1),x),A(entries(k),1:3))) && ...
                    any(arrayfun(@(x) isequal(A(entries(j),2),x),A(entries(k),1:3))) && ...
                    any(arrayfun(@(x) isequal(A(entries(j),3),x),A(entries(k),1:3)))) %check if each of the A{j,1:3} is in A(k,1:3)
                        solutionvector(entries(k))=false; %delete it in the solution vector and
                        c(entries(k))=0; %delete it from the check list
                end
            end    
       end
    end %end if c==i>1
end

B=A(solutionvector,:);%only get the cells hat are left
```

please check with a bigger sample if it is working correctly